# Wordpress Get User information after login or Signup

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to get User information after **Login or Signup** in Wordpress, I have tried several means but the `is_user_logged_in()` doesn't seem to work.

It always prints out "Welcome, Visior", even when the user logs in successfully.

The `is_user_logged_in()` only works inside the Wordpress theme scripts itself, but doesn't work when I use it in add add_action.

Is there any other way to check if user has loggedin, so I can easily get users information?

```
function get_user_information(){

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo 'Welcome, registered user!';

        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $email = $current_user->user_email;

    } else {
        echo 'Welcome, visitor!'; 

    }
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'get_user_information' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
 function get_user_information() {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

           echo ( 'Welcome, registered user!'. esc_html( $current_user->user_email ) );

        } else {
            echo( 'Welcome, visitor!' );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'loop_start', 'get_user_information' );
```

Comment: Thanks, But i am trying to get user_phone and that isn't working as well

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this:

echo ( 'Welcome, registered user!'. esc_html( $current_user->user_email ) );
$user_phone = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID,'user_phone');
You are getting $user_phone as array then write like: echo $user_phone[0]; 
Otherwise write like: echo $user_phone;
```